# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'filter_on_search' Python Django

Tags: python, django

Can anyone please suggest me why I am getting this error.

Following is model with Manager

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name   = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    customer_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    customer_email  = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    customer_dob    = models.DateField()
    customer_remarks= models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True)
    row_status      = models.BooleanField(choices=ROW_STATUS, default=True)
    created_date    = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_date    = models.DateTimeField()

    objects         = MyClassManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.customer_name

    def as_dict(self):
        """
        Create data for datatables ajax call.
        """
        return {'customer_name': self.customer_name,
                'customer_mobile': self.customer_mobile,
                'customer_dob': self.customer_dob,
                }
```

Manager Starts here ---------

```
class MyClassMixin(object):
    def q_for_search_word(self, word):
        """
        Given a word from the search text, return the Q object which you can filter on,
        to show only objects containing this word.
        Extend this in subclasses to include class-specific fields, if needed.
        """
        return Q(name__icontains=word) | Q(supplier__name__icontains=word)

    def q_for_search(self, search):
        """
        Given the text from the search box, search on each word in this text.
        Return a Q object which you can filter on, to show only those objects with _all_ the words present.
        Do not expect to override/extend this in subclasses.
        """
        q = Q()
        if search:
            searches = search.split()
            for word in searches:
                q = q & self.q_for_search_word(word)
        return q

    def filter_on_search(self, search):
        """
        Return the objects containing the search terms.
        Do not expect to override/extend this in subclasses.
        """
        return self.filter(self.q_for_search(search))

class MyClassQuerySet(QuerySet, MyClassMixin):
    pass

class MyClassManager(models.Manager, MyClassMixin):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return MyClassQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
```

This is my view  -----

```
class MyAPI(JSONViewMixin, View):
    "Return the JSON representation of the objects"
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        class_name = kwargs.get('cls_name')
        params = request.GET
        # make this api general enough to handle different classes
        klass = getattr(sys.modules['mudraapp.models'], class_name)

        # TODO: this only pays attention to the first sorting column
        sort_col_num = params.get('iSortCol_0', 0)
        # default to value column
        sort_col_name = params.get('mDataProp_{0}'.format(sort_col_num), 'value')
        search_text = params.get('sSearch', '').lower()
        sort_dir = params.get('sSortDir_0', 'asc')
        start_num = int(params.get('iDisplayStart', 0))
        num = int(params.get('iDisplayLength', 25))
        obj_list = klass.objects.all()
        sort_dir_prefix = (sort_dir=='desc' and '-' or '')
        if sort_col_name in col_name_map:
            sort_col = col_name_map[sort_col_name]
            obj_list = obj_list.order_by('{0}{1}'.format(sort_dir_prefix, sort_col))

        filtered_obj_list = obj_list
        if search_text:
            filtered_obj_list = obj_list.filter_on_search(search_text) //Here I am getting error

        d = {"iTotalRecords": obj_list.count(),                # num records before applying any filters
            "iTotalDisplayRecords": filtered_obj_list.count(), # num records after applying filters
            "sEcho":params.get('sEcho',1),                     # unaltered from query
            "aaData": [obj.as_dict() for obj in filtered_obj_list[start_num:(start_num+num)]] # the data
        }

        return self.json_response(d)
```

I am using this code for datatable pagination and search pagination works good but while search it gives error
I am following following Tutorial for this
http://racingtadpole.com/blog/datatables-with-ajax-and-django/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you have created in `MyClassManager` has the [wrong name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset):

```
def get_query_set(self):
```

Which should instead be:

```
# query_set -> queryset
def get_queryset(self):
```

Comment: Thanks, issue solved. But now I am getting  this error , can you please help me out -- FieldError at /Customer/
Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: created_date, customer_dob, customer_email, customer_id, customer_mobile, customer_name, customer_remarks, referance_id, row_status, updated_date

Comment: In the `q_for_search_word` method change `name__icontains` to `customer_name__icontains`. The field on your `Customer` model is called `customer_name` and not `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `filter_on_search` on your queryset. Instead, you need to use it in lieu of `objects`.

So, you would star by doing

```
obj_list = klass.filter_on_search
```

However, looks like you may want to move all of your logic from the view to the manager.

For what it's worth, there is an awesome package that does exactly what you want in integrating Django with Datatables: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datatables-view